Que extensión de archivo ejecutable usa MACOS?
Estoy creando un archivo .sh que hace una salutación sencilla. Es así:
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Buenos días, cómo se llama? "
read $name
echo "Usted se llama $name"

No es muy difícil, pero quiero hacer que se pueda ejecutar también en MACOS. Así que aqui mi pregunta:

Cuál es el archivo de ejecución de mac?
Existe algún compilador para hacer esto (tal como shc para linux → windows, para linux → mac?)

Un Saludo

igual q en linux chmod +x elScript.sh y ya te lo toma

Para esto, primero asegura tu archivo que es el script bash tenga permisos de ejecución:
 chmod +x archivo.sh

al asignar permisos, simplemente ejecútalo de esta forma:
./archivo.sh

incluso en Linux es similar
Con respecto a

"Existe algún compilador para hacer esto (tal como shc para linux →
windows, para linux → mac?)"

No existe un compilador para convertir tus scripts de uno a otro sistema operativo.

Lo del .sh me queda claro, pero leí en un documento que MAC tenia un formato de ejecución (aparte del .sh) que era algo como .app . Yo lo que busco también es hacer el archivo .app (creo que está en binario, corrigeme si estoy equivocado). Es posible?
